# Creating objects in object array from a string array

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, object

When I print the object array out, the output is Project.Class. 
The intended output is to show each object.

The array has already been declared outside of the method.

I tried using mutators however the output was the same.

Comment: override  ToString() on your Station Class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your `Console.WriteLine(stations[i]);`. You've not posted your stations object definition but you need to reference what properties you want to show. Otherwise you will just write out your object.

```
Console.WriteLine(stations[i].stationNo);
Console.WriteLine(stations[i].stationName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override ToString() method of that object class and emplement the method to return the specific properties what you want to print.
And inisde a loop you can call that ToString() method of that object to print that object information.